# UK visa refusal for not showing strong family ties in Nigeria

Tags: uk, paperwork, visa-refusals, nigerian-citizens

I am Nigerian and I applied for a UK visa, but was refused. I provided all the required documents ranging from bank statements to introduction letter from the company I work with to my tax card to flight/hotel reservation etc. Indeed I provided all the requirements they asked for. I applied for general visitor visa. The reason for being rejected is that they said I have no asset or property or strong family ties to prove that I will come back to my country.

Is it a crime for a single girl that has no asset or property to apply for visa and how would I have to prove to them that I have family ties here in Nigeria? Why on Earth would I leave my good paid job for an unsure circumstance in UK? I only want to go on vacation. I need advice on how to prove to them that I have strong family ties. I am an orphan from a family of 7 kids and I happen to be the last child. I have 11 nieces and nephews and a lot of cousins.

Comment: For your first question: there is no crime in being single.  For the other questions, if you edit your question to include the relevant paragraphs (exact text of what they said) you will get a more precise and higher quality answer. They would not normally refuse on lack of 'strong ties' alone...

Comment: `I have 11 nieces and nephews and a lot of cousins` Are they dependent on you. If yes use that in your application. Did you provide your return flight details ? `why on earth would i leave my good paid job for an unsure circumstance in Uk` Many do that, hence you would need to prove your case, no fault of yours though.

Answer (score 12):

I can recall a very similar question, and being a single male with nobody depending on me, I can share the same experience.

The flight bookings, hotel reservations, and bank statements all prove that you have enough funds to spend during your stay. This is, however, only a part of you that they evaluate.

Single people with a lot of freedom to move to a different country are high-risk people. People visiting a country on a tourist visa and staying there happens more often that you think. I do not want to emphasize on a certain nation, but there was a nice documentary about such people in the UK.

You need to understand that it's nothing personal or any fault in you. It's just that they see anyone with such characteristics as high risk.

- If you are still studying, mention that in your application. If you have a degree that you have to complete, that is generally considered a tie to your home country.
- Long term lease, long term job contracts, and anything like that basically proves that you are purely visiting the country for tourism can increase your chance too.

If your passport is new, with 0 or only a few visa/entry seals, that is a red flag for them too. A person outside the EU taking their first trip to UK: kinda alarming isn't it?

Make up your mind, and visit some neighboring countries first. The older your passport is, more convincing it is in their eyes that you really have the traveling spirit.

You can also try as an organized tour, but that is no way to travel (just my opinion). I wish you good luck!

Answer (score 3):

How I proved my family ties was by providing them with an official family card/certificate signed by the local government listing my name and my other family members' names in the certificate.

Comment: @blackbird57: This doesn't look like a new question, but an actual attempt to _answer_ this one.