# Can I apply for a UK visit visa before the expiry date of a Tier 4 visa?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

Some people say that it is possible. I also heard that the Embassy will have to invalidate the Tier 4 visa. If they do invalidate it, does the British embassy place a cancelled stamp on the Tier 4 visa or do they cross a line through it?  The reason why i am asking it that I currently hold Tier 4 visa that is valid until next four months, however, i finished my course in the UK and am aware that my circumstances have changed and as such I have to apply for a visit visa if i want to visit the UK soonest.

My second question is regarding evidence proving family ties. I currently earn a living from the UAE and i am resident here. However, I am a Ugandan national and also single. How then will I prove family ties if I am resident in a different country other than that where my extended family is? Of course I can prove that I will return because of the economic ties to the UAE, but how can i prove family ties to UAE, since my extended family lives in a different country?

Comment: Worth reading: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45456/uk-visa-refusal-for-not-showing-strong-family-ties-in-nigeria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read things correctly, you are:

- Currently residing in the UAE
- Have finished your education in the UK and left
- Want to visit the UK again, for non-student purposes

According to this [article](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/revocation-of-an-entry-clearance-ecb18/revocation-of-an-entry-clearance-ecb18#ecb181-when-can-an-eco-revoke-an-entry-clearance) (at least my understanding of it) an ECO will not cancel a existing Tier 4 Student visa that you have already used to enter the UK.

You may however be refused entry under [paragraph 320, 321](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-9-grounds-for-refusal#pt9clearance) if you try and use your Tier 4 Visa to enter and the IO determines that your change of circumstance invalidates your visa, however this should not happen obviously, as you will be entering as a visitor on a general visit visa.

I am confused as to what you mean by 'proving family ties', in the visit visa application, it does ask you to list the details of your Mother and Father, however there is no requirement to *prove* this in your application, unless specifically asked to.

What I think you mean is, how are you going to show that family is one of the reasons you will leave the UK at the end of your visit. You cannot prove this, as you already said, because your family lives in Uganda and you do not. Don't worry, this is not something that severely affects your application. If you can prove beyond reasonable doubt via other means (economic ties as you said, for example, like a job in the UAE), then that should not be an issue.

Please correct me if I have misunderstood anything in your question.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head with clear and succinct answers. My questions are well answered. Thank you so much Joel.

Comment: Feel free to mark the question as answered by clicking the tick mark next to my question! :) Glad to help!

Comment: You can improve this answer by providing where the OP can find Paragraph 320, 321.

Comment: Done :) Didn't think I had to since it wasn't too relevant to OP's situation if we was going to get a visit visa anyway, but I suppose it is always better to be thorough! Thanks!